# MySQL: How to search record for every month between two dates in mysql, return 0 if null ? with group by date clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show the data of all months between two dates even if the records of that months are not present in the table, like my where clause is

`date(created_on) between '2017-01-01' and '2018-02-02' group by year(created_on),month(created_on)`

So, I want to show records from January 2017 till February 2018 if there is no record show 0.

[Here is the link to SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fbdc6/6/0)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: shameless self promo. Here's a writeup. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/